# MySQL count per item

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to make a mysql query that will count the number of zeros and ones per item, in the following way:
Table:

```
    ID    |    PollID    |    Value
------------------------------------
    1     |      1       |     1
    2     |      1       |     1
    3     |      2       |     0
    4     |      2       |     1
    5     |      1       |     0
```

And the result I want is:

```
    Poll    |    one    |    zero
----------------------------------
      1     |     2     |     1
      2     |     1     |     1
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest possible answer in `MySQL` because it supports boolean arithmetic.

```
SELECT  PollID,
        SUM(value = 1) AS `One`,
        SUM(value = 0) AS `Zero`
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY PollID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36771/1)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      select table.pollid,
      Switch(table.value Like 1, 1)AS one,
      Switch(table.value Like 0, 1)AS zero       
      from table
      group by pollid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select z.pollid,z.ones,s.zeros 
  from (select a.pollid,count(a.value) as ones from test a
    where a.value=1
group by a.pollid) z   
left join   
    (select b.pollid,count(b.value) as zeros from test b  
     where b.value=0 group by b.pollid) s    
on z.pollid=s.pollid;
```